# Can I really exchange money in Forex?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, foreign-currency

Suppose I've got Euros. Suppose I need dollars.

How can I transfer/exchange my euros into dollars in Forex?

I know I can do it in any currency exchange stall. But Forex currency rates look more interesting because I have bigger amounts and don't want to loose difference.

Comment: If by “Forex”, you’re talking about a business, it would be best to ask them directly about the amounts you have in mind. They’re not bound by any answers we provide here.

Comment: @Lawrence OP is talking about the global [foreign exchange market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_market).

Comment: The answer is simply No, you need millions of dollars to access forex markets.  Note that if you simply use the two biggest consumer exchange companies,  ofx.com or transferwise, the rate you will get is so close to the market rate that it doesn't matter.  (Just BTW. Note that even if you were a billionaire, and you used the actual markets to trade tens of millions of dollars .... there a *huge* fees involved in running such a setup.)